# calling a function - when can the reference object be omitted?

Tags: javascript, function

I am learning javascript and I noticed that when calling a built-in function on some objects/classes, sometimes the reference is omitted but then at other times this caused the code to break. For example in

```
document.write("<p>calling 'write' of the current document object</p>")
```

you cannot omit "document". But in

```
var x=window.prompt("enter a value")
Number.isNaN(x)
```

you can omit both "window" and "Number" to become

```
var x=prompt("enter a value")
isNaN(x)
```

Why the two situations are different?

Thanks

Comment: thanks all for your quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

`window` is the global scope in web browsers.

MDN has a great explanation of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.window

`isNaN` is also available off of `window` but it isn't the same function as `Number.isNaN`. Running `isNaN == Number.isNaN` results in `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The `window` object is the global scope in Javascript in a browser. The `document` object is not. (The reason that you can use `document` directly, is that it's actually `window.document` and the `window` reference can be omitted.)

The reason that you can use `isNaN` with and without specifying the `Number` object is that there is both a [`isNaN` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and a [`Number.isNaN` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) (part of the next version of ECMAScript). They are similar, but doesn't work exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, all globals are actually properties of the "global object." In the web browser environment, that global object has a property, `window`, that it uses to refer to itself. So `prompt` refers to the global `prompt`; `window.prompt` refers to the global `window`, and then to its `prompt` property, which comes to the same thing. Consequently, `window.` is redundant when retrieving a global variable's value (unless the global variable has been *shadowed* by a local or intermediary declaration).

The `Number.isNaN` situation is quite different: From the beginning of JavaScript through the current specification (ES5), there is no `Number.isNaN` function; it's just [`isNaN`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.4), which is global. ES6 [adds a new, **slightly different** function](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-number.isnan) on the `Number` constructor that does what `isNaN` does, but *without* converting its argument to a number first.

Example:

```
console.log(isNaN("foo"));        // true
console.log(Number.isNaN("foo")); // false
```

The first says `true` because the standalone `isNaN` coerces its argument to a number before doing the check; since `Number("foo")` is `NaN`, the check returns true. `Number.isNaN` says false because it *doesn't* coerce, and so what it's checking isn't a number at all, and so can't be the special `NaN` number value.

Answer (score 0):

`document` is equal to `window.document`. In browsers, the global scope is referred to `window`, therefore simply you can omit `window`.

Actually those are two different functions

[Number.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) is ES6 function, but another global function [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) exists already. ES6 version of this function is providing the way to [reliably check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Confusing_special-case_behavior) whether x is NaN or not